# How to interpret GLM coefficients?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model

I am reproducing the results from COMPAS analysis done by [propublica](https://github.com/propublica/compas-analysis/blob/master/Compas%20Analysis.ipynb) and I needed some help understanding how they handled interpretation of GLM coefficients. Score_factor is a variable indicating risk of recidivism and its regressed against variables like race, gender etc. The model is given below.

```
Call:
glm(formula = score_factor ~ gender_factor + age_factor + race_factor + 
    priors_count + crime_factor + two_year_recid, family = "binomial", 
    data = df)

Coefficients:    
                            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                 -1.52554    0.07851 -19.430  < 2e-16 ***
gender_factorFemale          0.22127    0.07951   2.783 0.005388 ** 
age_factorGreater than 45   -1.35563    0.09908 -13.682  < 2e-16 ***
age_factorLess than 25       1.30839    0.07593  17.232  < 2e-16 ***
race_factorAfrican-American  0.47721    0.06935   6.881 5.93e-12 ***
race_factorAsian            -0.25441    0.47821  -0.532 0.594717    
race_factorHispanic         -0.42839    0.12813  -3.344 0.000827 ***
race_factorNative American   1.39421    0.76612   1.820 0.068784 .  
race_factorOther            -0.82635    0.16208  -5.098 3.43e-07 ***
priors_count                 0.26895    0.01110  24.221  < 2e-16 ***
crime_factorM               -0.31124    0.06655  -4.677 2.91e-06 ***
two_year_recid               0.68586    0.06402  10.713  < 2e-16 ***
```

From the model above, they concluded  that "Black defendants are 45% more likely than white defendants to receive a higher score correcting for the seriousness of their crime, previous arrests, and future criminal behavior." (Note race_factorWhite is part of intercept) based on following calculation:

```
control <- exp(-1.52554) / (1 + exp(-1.52554))
exp(0.47721) / (1 - control + (control * exp(0.47721)))
[1] 1.452841
```

I am aware that we can get change in odds ratio of score_factor between white and black defendants by doing  exp(0.47721). But I am not sure what the calculation with control and intercept is doing. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original author of the analysis was kind enough to respond and clear this up for me. The calculation converts odds ratio (which are highly unintuitive) to relative risk (which is easier to understand). More details are provided [here](http://www.bmj.com/content/348/bmj.f7450.full?ijkey=NHT1YVsoX1RCm8r&keytype=ref).

The GLM coefficients only show the multiplicative change in odds ratio. so if p1 is the risk of getting a high score for black defendants and p0 is the risk of getting a high score for white defendants, then exp(0.47721) shows (p1/(1-p1))/(p0/(1-p0)). Unfortunately, this is not particularly easy to intuit. Relative risk (p1/p0) is a much simpler concept to understand and odds ratio can be converted to relative risk using the formula: Relative risk=odds ratio/(1−p0+(p0×odds ratio)). The calculation in the question accomplishes that.

Comment: It's great that you found an answer! However, leaving all the details behind a link means that your answer becomes useless once [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) sets in. It will be very helpful to future readers if you could add a short summary of what the link provides. Since it's a link to an academic paper, you might as well go ahead and provide a full academic citation. That Will go along way towards "future proofing" your answer.

Comment: The GLM coefficients only show the multiplicative change in odds ratio. so if p1 is the risk of getting a high score for black defendants and p0 is the risk of getting a high score for white defendants, then exp(0.47721) shows   (p1/(1-p1))/(p0/(1-p0)). Unfortunately, this is not particularly easy to intuit. Relative risk (p1/p0) is a much simpler concept to understand and odds ratio can be converted to relative risk using the formula: Relative risk=odds ratio/(1−p0+(p0×odds ratio)). The calculation in the question accomplishes that.

Comment: You should edit that into your main post (comments aren't searchable by users). You can use the "edit" button at the bottom left

Comment: @Rajesh In most cases you can estimate the relative risk directly with relative risk regression. Relative risk regression is a glm with binomial variance formula (var = mean * (1-mean)), but uses a log link. Attempt the analysis again with `family=binomial(link=log)` and you should get comparable results. I cannot advocate enough transforming ORs to RRs when possible.